# Get the depth of an Item

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml like this:

```
<A><B>test</B><B><B>test2</B></B><B><B><B>test2</B></B></B></A>
```

How can I get the level of each of these items using linq to xml

level of test=1 level of test2=2 level of test3=3

I have no idea how many nodes there will be or how many levels there will be.  I can write this as a recursive function but I thought linq to xml might have something better to offer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded your XML as an `XDocument` or `XElement` object,

`myXElement.AncestorsAndSelf().Count()`

should give you the depth of any given element.

Comment: There is no Count() method returned by AncestorsAndSelf.  Plus, the semantics of the above code will return a tree depth 1 greater than the actual 0-based depth.  Consider the code snippet below, which corrects these problems.

Comment: public static int GetDepth(this XElement element)
        {
            int Count = 0;
            foreach (XElement elem in element.Ancestors())
                Count++;
            return Count;
        }

Comment: There is a Count() method, it is a LINQ extension method. If you do not want to count the current element, use Ancestors() instead of AncestorsAndSelf().

Answer (score 0):

When you have a root element you can find depth of every text node as follows:

```
var depths =
  root.
    DescendantNodesAndSelf().
    Where(e => e.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text).
    Select(n => new { Text = n.ToString(), Depth = n.Parent.Ancestors().Count()});
```