# How to get depth of node

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the depth of an Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210162/get-the-depth-of-an-item)

I have xml like this:

```
 <Parent>
     <child>test</child>
     <child>
         <child>test2</child>
     </child> 
     <child> 
         <child>
             <child>test3</child>
         </child>
     </child>
 </Parent>
```

How can I get the level of each of these items using linq to xml

level of test=1 level of test2=2 level of test3=3

I have no idea how many nodes there will be or how many levels there will be. I can write this as a recursive function but I thought linq to xml might have something better to offer.

Comment: s/ASP.NET/.NET/ in tags: nothing about ASP.NET here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use xpath to calculate the node level. E.g. for the `<child>test3</child>`:

```
var element = d.XPathSelectElement("Parent/child/child/child");
var level = element.XPathSelectElements("ancestor::*").Count();
```

**EDIT**: [@Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67392/richard) in the comment suggests to calculate parent nodes without instantiating the `XElement` instances:

```
var level = (double)element.XPathEvaluate("count(ancestor::*)");
```

this saves  them

And of course you could use [`Ancestors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339717.aspx) method (as proposed in another answer) to get a collection of the ancestor elements of the node and count them:

```
var level = element.Ancestors().Count();
```

This will give you the same result.

Comment: I would suggest `level = element.XPathEvaluate("count(ancestor::*)") as int`: this saves instantiating the `XElement` instances only to then count them.

Comment: @Richard, thanks for the excellent suggestion. It seems this is the best solution. The only thing - the type of the returned expression is `double` not `int`.

Comment: The return as a double is because all numerics in XSLT is floating point, but clearly the result of count must be an integral value – probably should have preferred a cast to include explicit conversions :-).